# Creating a dictionary from unique entries in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a certain pandas data frame that looks like this:

|  | x | y | unit ID | leak/min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12 | 34 | 1 | 3.3 |
| 1 | 99 | 42 | 1 | 2.33 |
| 2 | 45 | 55 | 3 | 3.11 |

It runs upto 400 entries.

I would like to create a function that determines the number of unique units and then return a dictionary with subsets of the data frame. So the key is a string with unit IDs and each value is the dataframe of a subset of the original data frame.

I know how to find the unique values using this code; `uniqueValues = data['ID'].unique()` but having problems implementing the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you want something like this:

```
dict_dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby("unit ID")))

for key, val in dict_dfs.items():
    print(f"{key=}: \n {val} \n")

key=1: 
     x   y  unit ID  leak/min
0  12  34        1      3.30
1  99  42        1      2.33 

key=3: 
     x   y  unit ID  leak/min
2  45  55        3      3.11
```